# Zip::ZipFile File not found error with aws s3 in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, zip

Iam working on a rails application hosted on heroku and trying to unzip files. Iam storing zipfile using paperclip on amazon s3.

`zip_file.rb`

```
class ZipFile < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_attached_file :attachment, {}.merge(PAPERCLIP_STORAGE_OPTIONS)
end
```

My files are successfully getting stored on amazon. when I open the attachment url in browser it downloads the zip file. But in my console when I try to unzipfile it gives me the error:

```
u = ZipFile.last.attachment.url
Zip::ZipFile.open(u)
```

I get the error:

```
Zip::ZipError: File #{file_url} not found
```

I also used the `zipfile.attachment.path` to access the file but it returns the same error.

What is the issue? Please help.

Many thanks.